# How to deploy self managed EKS cluster with specific disk size

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

I would like to deploy a self managed EKS cluster with specific disk size.

Here's what I've tried so far :

```
module "eks" {
  source                   = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version                  = "~> 19.5"

  self_managed_node_groups = {
    one => {
      disk_size                    = 50
      use_custom_launch_template   = false
    }
    
    # More nodes defined above... 
  }
}
```

But it does not seem to be applied.
Any help very appreciated.

I've tried to follow these steps : https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest/submodules/eks-managed-node-group#usage

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example that allowed me to solve that issue : https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/tree/v19.16.0/examples/self_managed_node_group.

Specifically, the `main.tf` file that states :

```
module "eks" {
  [...]
  self_managed_node_groups = {
    [...]
    complete = {
      [...]
      block_device_mappings = {
        xvda = {
          device_name = "/dev/xvda"
          ebs = {
            volume_size           = 75
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Source : https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v19.16.0/examples/self_managed_node_group/main.tf#L204.